# How to programmatically disable predictive view but enable autocorrection on textview in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uitextview, textfield

I am creating an app which has chat interface.i would like to disable predictive view but not the autocorrection feature of keyboard on textview.i used below one

```
message.autocorrectionType=UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo
```

it disabled both predictive and autocorrection feature.but i want to disable predictive only.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
message.spellCheckingType=UITextSpellCheckingTypeYes
message.autocorrectionType=UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo
```

hope works. :)

Comment: i have used the above one but it only highlight the wrong words .is there any other way to disable the predictive view of keyboard except the  UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo ?

Answer (score 0):

This line of code work fine

```
self.textField.spellCheckingType=UITextSpellCheckingTypeYes;
self.textField.autocorrectionType=UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```